# Different external and internal keyword name for Python function parameters?

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to have a different keyword name when calling a function than inside the function body itself? For example, in Swift you can define:

```
func person(with_name name: str) -> Person {
    return Person(name: name)
}


var p = person(with_name: "Jeffry Mills") # p is now a person object with the name jeffry Mills
```

Is there any way to mimic this in Python? Although Python 3.7 allows type annotations the mirrored syntax is not valid:

```
def person(with_name name: str): # Invalid Syntax
    return Person(name=name)

p = person(with_name="Jeffry Mills") # Looking for something similar to this
```

I'm looking for this because I believe it helps with readability.

Edit:

Comments were asking for use cases. There are no use cases in which the method by which the problem is solved is fundamentally different, I just think it helps with readability.

My above code works as an example. When you want to create a new instance of person through our wrapper function, it writes

```
person(with_name="Jeffry")
```

So when you call it, it reads much more like a sentences. "Person with name Jeffry" reads much more fluently IMO, than "Person and name is Jeffry".

Comment: Fortunately, no. Can you name one use case where this is actually helpful?

Comment: You can assign the variable to another variable inside the function, but again, I don't see any legit use case. Just use a meaningful name to begin with

Comment: I edited to add use cases @DeepSpace , I am using meaningful names here in both cases but depending on context I believe having separate names may improve readability, although it would complicate the function definition syntax some.

Comment: No. It doesn't improve readability. It just adds complexity, both syntactically and logically

Comment: That's completely a matter of opinion yet you say it like fact @DeepSpace. When calling the function, it reads better in my opinion. "In my opinion". Clearly it does make it harder to read the function definition since it requires an additional name specification and you have to know the syntax. Logically speaking the two function identically except in the case I was presenting there are two names for parameters (one for inside the function one for calling the function). So logically it makes sense the same as it did before having the two names for a parameter.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a singleton, where you first time you do `p=person(name='Jeffry')` it creates a new person, and subsequent uses of `person(name='Jeffry')` simply returns the previously created person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to understand what you're asking without a concrete example or use case. However, if all you want is for `p = Person(with_name="Jeffry")` to return a `Person` object with the `name` attribute set to "Jeffry", that's pretty easy to do. Your function can simply iterate over the arguments and change any that begin with `with_` to the variant without the `with_`.

For example:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def person(**kwargs):
    attrs = {}
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if key.startswith("with_"):
            key_name = key[5:]
            attrs[key_name] = value

    return Person(**attrs)

p = person(with_name="Jeffry")
print("name is", p.name)
```

When run, it outputs this:

```
name is Jeffry
```

Personally I would never allow this code to pass a code review, because it makes the code more confusing to anyone who understands python. They would find it very confusing to have to pass `with_name=foo` in order to set `name=foo`.

Comment: Although I did ask the question, I'll admit there's really no use case where this is necessary, I was just wondering if there was a feature similar to that of Swift's. Your code does the job. The only use for it is improved optional readability if you think the with_name syntax is better. Apparently there is not a feature like this, and although your solution works I think it would be foolish to ever implement such code, since it requires the specific "with_" it would be very quick to confuse and adds a layer of unnecessary complexity. I would only use a solution that is optional syntax.